# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to embed an applet

Tags: java, applet

So I wrote my code for a Snake game for a kid I know and the darned thing won't embed itself in html.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Snake</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet width=200 height=100 code="SnakeGame.class">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

and I am certain that the class file is in the same directory as `snake.html`, but it still refuses to run.  It always replies:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SnakeGame (wrong name: view/SnakeGame)
```

Does anyone know why? Thanks.

EDIT:

the folder `view` contains: `SnakeGame.class`, and all the other classes for the game, as well as the html

Comment: show us the directory structure.

Comment: Is your class file in the **same** folder as your html file?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `SnakeGame` class in in the `view` package, so your applet tag should look like:

```
<applet width=200 height=100 code="view.SnakeGame.class">
```

Generally you specify 'package.class' in the 'code' attribute, i.e. `com.stackoverflow.MyClass.class`