# Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Chase (wrong name: pong/Chase)

Tags: java

I have created an applet program using Eclipse IDE. Now im creating .html file as below:

```
<html>
<APPLET CODE="Chase.class" width=500 height=400>
</APPLET>
</html>
```

When Im executing this file the error im getting is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Chase (wrong name: pong/Chase)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In Eclipse IDE is have created new project and packaged the program into "pong" folder.

Can anybody explain why this error is occuring?

Edit:

Adding few Chase.java code lines, for clarification. It is simple applet:

```
package pong;


import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;



public class Chase extends Applet implements Runnable
{ ...  }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298988/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-when-trying-to-embed-an-applet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no class name `Chase` in your classpath.

`wrong name` specifies there might be mistake with class name with package specified.

if your class declares `package` for example

```
package a;
public class MyApplet extends Applet{}
```

then in HTML give `a.MyApplet`

**Update**

in your case it seems

`<APPLET CODE="pong.Chase.class" width=500 height=400>`

also dir structure should be

```
- - - - -
      |
      |-your html file
      |-pong folder
          |
          |- Chases.class
```

will do if package name is `pong`

Comment: Tried to use the help. The error still somes as:oad: class pong/Chase.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pong.Chase.class
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)....etc

Comment: Yes the package name is "pong" and after doing the above steps it works, when executed independently. However when i have to add a custom html code into a custom webpage of a website then the error is same as above.

Comment: `when i have to add a custom html code into a custom webpage of a website` please explain

Comment: widget based website creators provide a widget where in we can drag a HTML Code widget into our webpage and add a html code snippet into it.This is where i want to add the applet code. So that the applet is excutable on the page.

Comment: ok then you also need to provide `class` in the same structure shown above in that server in order to load applet

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is basically as @Jigar Joshi has noted, but with a slight wrinkle to it.  I think you have a class whose FQN is "pong.Chase", but you have set up the classpath so that the directory containing "Chase.class" is on the classpath.  Then you've told the applet loader to look for a class as "Chase.class".

The classloader has found the bytecode file, but then when it attempted to load it, it has noticed that the classes FQN is "pong.Chase" rather than "Chase" ... as inferred by the name that you gave.  Ergo ... a `NoClassDefFoundError`, with a message *that tells you that the class name is incorrect*.

The fix is to make sure that the parent directory of the "pong" directory is on the classpath, and use:

```
<APPLET CODE="pong.Chase.class" width=500 height=400></APPLET>
```

Alternatively - use the `codeBase` attribute.

Alternatively 2 - get rid of the `package` declaration in your Java class.

Alternatively 3 - use the `<object>` element.  The `<applet>` element is deprecated.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html

Comment: the alternative 2 works no doubt. i have to add this applet code snippet into a webpage. When added, the error is same as earlier. But when the html file is executed independently is works. Why is it so?

Comment: @GamDroid - I suspect it is the directory structure; see @Jigar  Joshi's updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the package part in your applet tag:

```
<APPLET CODE="pong.Chase.class" width=500 height=400>
</APPLET>
```