# is it possible to create a java applet, during execution of another java application

Tags: java, applet, jung

I have been developing a Java application which executes a long series of queries and calculations, and presents its results as a series of HTML pages. For visualizing graphs I have been playing around with JUNG library for a while, and it appears as the real strength of the library is the support for user interaction, which is of course unavailable when the graph is saved as a static image (PNG in my case).

I was wondering if it would be:

a) possible

b) feasible

c) sensible

... to create an applet, during execution of the main application, which then can be insert to the HTML reports and can be used interactively after the application has finished execution and the user goes through the report pages.

If this is not possible due to technical reasons; do you have any alternative recommendations/ suggestions as to how I can achieve something like this?

Thanks,

**EDIT:** Just to clarify the concept, the "main" application is a link in a chain of events, and thus has so separate GUI. The idea with the applet is NOT to mimic or transport all the stuff from the main app to a HTML page, but to make it possible to use interactive tools that come with JUNG library, when the user is reviewing the graphical results AFTER the execution of the main software has finished.

Let me know if the concept is still rather unclear and I'll give a second attempt to explain things in further detail.

**UPDATE:** Following the advices I got, thnx to @boffinBrain & @AndrewThompson, I wrote my applet, and placed in a package in my project along with other visualization related classes. The hierarchy is as follows:

```
my.domain.project
my.domain.project.tests
my.domain.project.visualization
```

Now the HTML reports are created at an arbitrary location on the local drive, this is a feature as the user gives an output folder prior to running the "main" application. In my `ReportGenerator` class (which generates these HTML files) I have the following bit of code:

```
File bin = new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString());
String codebase = bin.getParent();
System.out.println(codebase);
String archive = "lib/collections-generic-4.01/collections-generic-4.01.jar";
String applet_name = "bin/my.domain.project.visualization.HierarchyGraphApplet.class";
```

`codebase` printout shows: `file:/home/username/workspace/project` which is correct what I'd expected. Under the project folder there's bin/ and lib/, and inside bin there is the right hierarchy of folders all the way down to my applet class which also exists.

Now why did I write all this down; well because when I try to run my applet on the reports I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bin/my/domain/project/visualization/HierarchyGraphApplet (wrong name: my/domain/project/visualization/HierarchyGraphApplet)
```

I have read similar questions like: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780371/error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-chase-wrong-name-pong-chase) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298988/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-when-trying-to-embed-an-applet) but it seems like the problem is somewhere else. I double checked the spelling etc...
Is there something simple I am missing, or is there a more complicated problem at hand?

Comment: I do not quite see the advantage of the HTML at all.  Why not present the results within an area of the main GUI?

Comment: @Andrew Because then the results can be viewed by anyone, without having to install the application.

Comment: So the 'Java application' works on the server side?  Note that if you wish to replicate 'all the behavior' of the application into an applet, the end user will have to download (and 'install' as far as applets are cached) the applet?

Comment: @Andrew: well because the main application does not have a GUI. It's designed to be a part/module in a larger workflow. I'll try to clarify the concept in the question text.

Comment: @posdef My apologies, I mistook Robin's speculation for a reply from you.

Comment: @posdef:  There is not enough information to answer the current question.  I would need, the directory structure/location of the HTML, applet Jars (and any other loose class files), and the content of the Jar files to give any sort of confident answer.  I suggest you collect that information and start a new thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this example will give you some ideas to pursue.  It creates data files used as 'reports' for consumption by the applet(s).

Because the applet gains the data via an input file whose title is specified in an applet `param`.  The content of the data file is only limited by the requirements of the report, your skill to create it & parse it, ..and available disk space.  ;)

Compile & run the `main(String[])` to (hopefully) see 2 web pages open in tabs of your browser.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

/** Simplistic example, not intended to show good I/O practices
or Exception handling for the sake of brevity. */
public class Reporter extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
        String input = getParameter("input");

        JEditorPane report = new JEditorPane();
        report.setText("Problem loading input file");
        add(report);

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(getDocumentBase(), input);
            report.setPage(url);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** The main represents our report generator.  It is part
    of the applet class only in order to create an SSCCE. Good
    design would imply that it might be in a class ReportGenerator,
    while the applet is in class ReportViewer. */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File f;
        String title = "1";
        String data = "apples";

        createInput(title, data);
        f = createHTML(title);
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(f.toURI());

        title = "2";
        data = "oranges";

        createInput(title, data);
        f = createHTML(title);
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(f.toURI());

        System.out.println( "End of report generation.." );
    }

    public static void createInput(String title, String data) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("data" + title + ".txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        pw.println(data);

        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }

    public static File createHTML(String title) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("Data" + title + ".html");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);

        pw.println("<html>");
        pw.println("<title>");
        pw.println("Data " + title);
        pw.println("<title>");
        pw.println("<body>");
        pw.println("<h1>");
        pw.println("Data " + title);
        pw.println("</h1>");
        pw.println("<applet ");
        pw.println("code='Reporter'");
        pw.println("width='400'");
        pw.println("height='400'");
        pw.println(">");
        pw.println("<param name='input' value='data" + title + ".txt'>");
        pw.println("</applet>");
        pw.println("</body>");
        pw.println("</html>");

        pw.flush();
        pw.close();

        return f;
    }
}
```

---

In relation to further questions:

> ..does the given code assume that the html reports and the applet are located in the same folder?

Not necessarily.  The `input` parameter might specify `../other/data3.txt` for the `other` directory at the same level as the one contained by the `HTML`, or `/reports/data3.txt` for a `reports` directory at the root of the site.

> ..As you have also noted, in a real-life example the code for the applet would most likely be in its own class, would that pose any complications as to how it would be incorporated into the html files (which are generated in a separate class, named ReportGenerator)?

It would require only slight changes to point to the `applet.jar` as opposed to the `application.jar`.  Use a `codebase` to separate the `HTML` from the directory of the `applet.jar` (though archives can also be accessed via relative or absolute URLs).

Comment: Really nice example, thank you! I have a couple of question about it though; for instance, does the given code assume that the html reports and the applet are located in the same folder? As you have also noted, in a real-life example the code for the applet would most likely be in its own class, would that pose any complications as to how it would be incorporated into the html files (which are generated in a separate class, named ReportGenerator)?

Comment: Thanks again for the further instructions, Andrew. I have been playing around with the code I have, and the example you've provided, although this time I'm having difficulties with launching the applet. I wasn't sure if it should go as further details into this question or into a separate question; but I'll update the question with the relevant info, would really appreciate if you could cast an eye on that. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely feasible to create an applet to display the data, but you don't want to dynamically generate a new one each time.  You want to create a separate, stand-alone applet which can generate your graphs/reports from a set of input data in text format, and then when you create the HTML page, supply the report data using an applet parameter (using the PARAM tag).

Comment: Good idea, I have thought of it as well, but wouldn't that leave me with the following two new problems: 1) Try and mash together all info needed to create the graphs into a small enough parameter; and 2) having a second batch of code to distribute. The ideal scenario would be to distribute the main application as a JAR, which then takes care of everything else when it runs. So far I have built the whole thing like that. What are the complications with dynamically generating an applet?

Comment: The idea of dynamically generating applet source code, compiling it and making a jar out of it sounds far more complicated than it needs to be.  Packaging up your entire app is also a security risk because it would provide clients with code which can be reverse-engineered and might allow access to your server.  I would definitely recommend writing a lightweight applet designed specifically for viewing your reports, and use a standard data format like CSV (no need to mash the data together - you can use one PARAM tag per table).

Comment: Well, the thing is there is no server. The HTML pages are created at the local computer where the java application (aka main) is run. But I guess the principle stands; I could try to write an applet, package it, and keep in the JAR of the main application. Which can then be copied to the reports folder, by the main application during runtime. Would that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but you'll essentially be storing report data inside jars, instead of just storing the data.  That's a waste of space, and also means you'll be forced to use old versions of the viewer to view old reports, rather than just use the latest viewer to open an old data file (provided the format remains consistent).